# MoveFile() Works, but returns error 2 (file not found)

Tags: c++, winapi, movefileex

I'm using the function Movefile() (in C). I can see the file moved from the source folder to the destination (means the MoveFile success) but when I do GetLastError() I get error no. 2 (ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND).

What can be the problem?

The code is:

```
_snprintf(szSrcPath, MAX_PATH, "%s/%s/%s.jpg", NPath, imagePathFromAdmin, username);
_snprintf(szDestPath, MAX_PATH, "%s/Images/Storage/%s/%d/%s.jpg", NPath, domain, sub_folder, username);
strcpy(imagePathStorgae,szDestPath);
MoveFile(szSrcPath,szDestPath);
err=GetLastError();
```

Comment: third parameter for [CopyFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851(v=vs.85).aspx) says the call should fail if dest file exist. so if you run it more than once for same file it will fail. I think this is where the error comes from.

Comment: Try this:: if( !MoveFile(szSrcPath, szDestPath) ) { err = GetLastError() ; } Now tell us, what does your "err" contains.

Comment: Is "MoveFile()" a C function ?

Comment: @Abhineet It is a Windows API function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365239(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thats what I thought. Actually the question was targeted to OP :-D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do *not* get the error code if a function succeeds, the value is not valid. Instead check the value returned by the actual function (i.e. the `MoveFile` function return value) and if that indicates that an error happened, *then* you can check what the error was.

Answer (score 7):

You are only meant to call `GetLastError` if the API function call reported failure. Check the return value of both `CopyFile` and `MoveFile`. If either returns `FALSE` then the API call failed and then, and only then, is it valid to call `GetLastError`.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365239.aspx) states it like this:

> **Return value**
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error
>   information, call `GetLastError`.

What is happening is that `MoveFile` succeeds and does not modify the last error value. Then when you call `GetLastError` it returns an error code for some other call to an API function, that happened before you called `MoveFile`. You should write the code like this:

```
if (!MoveFile(szSrcPath,szDestPath))
{
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    // handle the error
}
```